# How to branch and deploy versions of the same repo

Tags: deployment, version, branch, repo

I'd to understand how my team can handle building a components library and then from time to time making a sub-site of the major versions like it is shown in this image of angular material components.

How would you keep track of the versions in the repo and then how would you deploy them to the sub-sites?

[image]